# Cannot access Native Module (undefined is not an object)

Tags: plugins, react-native, undefined

`native-country-picker` and when I run it I got the error:

> undefined is not an object NativeModules.CountryPicker.show

I tried to do these steps:

- `react-native upgrade`
- `rnpm link`
  (after the plugin install)
  and same error.

this is the country picker plugin
https://github.com/tofugear/react-native-country-picker

This is the code of the plugin:

```
'use strict';

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

var RNCountryPicker= NativeModules.CountryPicker;
var CountryPicker = {};

CountryPicker.show = function (callBack) {
  NativeModules.CountryPicker.show(callBack);
};

CountryPicker.hide = function () {
  RNCountryPicker.hide();
};

module.exports = CountryPicker;
```

And the error in the line:

> NativeModules.CountryPicker.show(callBack);
>
> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.CountryPicker.show')

Comment: Did you not follow the steps mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: @BradBumbalough yes i am